# Proper way to use cache rspec `let` value

Tags: ruby, rspec

I got a class like that:

```rb
class Calculation
  def initialize
    heavy_calculation
  end

  def result
    'ok'
  end

  def errors
    nil
  end

  private
  
  def heavy_calculation
    p "Performing CPU-heavy calculations"
  end
end
```

And RSpec for checking both public methods

```rb
describe Calculation do
  let(:calculations) { Calculation.new }

  it 'result equal ok' do
    expect(calculations.result).to eq('ok')
  end

  it 'errors equal nil' do
    expect(calculations.errors).to be_nil
  end
end
```

Running this code we got two times `"Performing CPU-heavy calculations"` in the terminal, so the Calculation constructor was called twice

I was trying to refactor this code so the constructor run only once - but didn't find any solution which works flawless, without running the calculation code twice, or without leaking values to other spec files

So any advice on how to solve that correctly?

Comment: What about setting an instance variable in `before(:all)`? Or, if adding new dependencies is acceptable, this thing might help: https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/recipes/let_it_be

Comment: Is't setting something in `before_all` result initalization of that variable in all specs if two or more specs are run?

Comment: Also using `before(:all)` is not adviced by https://github.com/rubocop/rspec-style-guide#ambiguous-hook-scope

Comment: As far as I remember if it is defined in the example group it is local to this example group.

Comment: `before(:context)` is the same in this ... hmmm context :) It is discouraged because the state may leak between the examples, but it your case this is _exactly the desired effect_, isn't it? So it is about a trade-off: you either have clean isolated tests but do heavy computations several times, or you memorize the heavy computations and have better tests suite performance but your tests are not isolated any more...

Comment: Yeah I thinkn you're right, using before(:all) solved the problem

But rubocop really don't like that solution according to style guide, maybe something to keep me and rubocop default config happy )

Comment: I think I agree with you with leaking and that either I leak and optimize test or keep rubocop happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think that there is no proper way to solve that problem

I basically have two choices:

1. Leak data (`Heavy calculation`) between examples via using `before(:all)` and thus not properly isolation tests cases
2. Isolate but perform heavy calculations several times

So either of those choices comes with different tradeoffs and I must choose one of them

And seems that leave tests in current way be more correct choice

Comment: You could also mock `heavy_calculation` as needed

Comment: @engineersmnky Fair enought, but I really need to perform those calculations )

Answer (score 1):

`let` is intended to be lazily evaluated.  The values declared by let are reset for each test so it makes sense that you see the constructor called once for each test.

If you are looking purely for a *test* optimization, then the solution is probably to abandon the use of `let`.  Rspec blocks are like any other ruby code so you can declare local variables.  The code below gives two passing results with only one (expensive) call to the constructor:

```
describe Calculation, type: :model do
  calculations = Calculation.new

  it 'result equal ok' do
    expect(calculations.result).to eq('ok')
  end

  it 'errors equal nil' do
    expect(calculations.errors).to be_nil
  end
end
```

If the issue is broader -- that you really only need to instantiate the class once and then track changes -- then you might want to investigate [Singleton](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.5/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html)

Comment: This is my first thought as a solution, but this will leak `Calculations.new` outside of this rspec

So if you run several rspec files - calculation will be done **before** running any tests even if antoher file is first

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share information between 2 `it` blocks may mean that those blocks can be merged into 1. So my proposed solution for this specific case would be to test `#new`.

```
describe Calculation do
  let(:calculations) { Calculation.new }

  it '#new' do
    expect(calculations.result).to eq('ok')
    expect(calculations.errors).to be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Agree that will work but I prefer one expect in one `it`

But in general terms it definitely solve my problem

Comment: I agree with that but in this case, if you cache data between different `it` blocks means that you are using the same class instance between different runs which will result in testing exactly the same thing as the 1 `it` block. Also running 2 `it` blocks instead of 1 would just make your test suite slower and more complex without offering any value.

Comment: Based on my personal preference the optimum here would be to group tests based on the class logic for example happy case vs unhappy case.